# Dissect a BCVideo object

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an object, which returns when i NSLog it: `BCVideo: id:1128597303001 name:Hana` I can dissect the name by doing [object name], but I need the id, and [object id] doesn't work. How do I get the id (from class BCvideo obviously) from the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is BCVideo class but i googled it and i found this :

http://docs.brightcove.com/en/iphone-sdk/bc-media-api/interface_b_c_video.html

So if it's that, you can retrieve id with properties videoId, referenceId and accountId according to your preferences

Comment: Sorry for not including that link, yeah, I tried their way by doing [object videoId], but that gives me an exc_bad_access (after the object is created).

Comment: can you edit your question to show the code where you try to access the videoId ? Maybe you try to use it like an object but videoId returns long long ??

Comment: im just trying to NSLog it, because i just need the number in a double to fetch other videos. so NSLog(@"Videoid: %@", [video videoId]);

Comment: Yes but if you use %@ in NSLog, it expects to have an object but videoId is long long, try instead NSLog(@"VideoId: %lld", [video videoId]);

Comment: Aww.. that was the answer. I didnt know the log for a long long.. I knew int and double but not lld.

Ill try and bookmark http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSLog. Thanks alot :)